# Transitioning from Coldfusion to PHP

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am getting ready to learn PHP. I am looking for advice from other ColdFusion developers out there who have made the transition. I'm also looking for a guide showing some tag equivalencies (fingers crossed). Thanks!

Comment: I don't think PHP has any "tags" like ColdFusion.  :(  You can use HTML tags, of course.  Here's a nice starting guide:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: To be honest, the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) is a very good starting point for learning about the language.

Comment: @Josh For future reference, you might want to have a read of http://w3fools.com/ (They're not a popular reference site in these quarters, as I've found to my peril in the past.) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you just accepted a terribly biased answer like `Best solution: stick with ColdFusion or Railo :)` from `ColdFusion is just better.`

However, if you are looking at an idea of commands I would say start by looking at some common string / functions in php by going through things that might matter to you like:

- arrays (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)
- strings (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

You could also look at some frameworks (MVC - similar to coldfusion MVC frameworks):

- CodeIgniter (http://codeigniter.com)
- CakePHP ([http://cakephp.org/](http://cakephp.org))

Hope that helps, rather than give a blatantly one sided answer.
There are large differences between CF & PHP however both are beginner friendly (from my perspective) and offer great documentation.